# How to determine if user is building debug from Skylark

Tags: bazel

Is there a way from the `ctx` variable within Skylark to determine if the user is building with debug mode (`-c dbg`). I'd like to make decisions in Skylark related to this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`print(ctx.var["COMPILATION_MODE"])`

Value will be "fastbuild", "dbg" or "opt".